# What is proper use of "coiffed"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Would writing "well-coiffed" automatically imply nicely styled hair, or do you need to say *well-coiffed hair* or something similarly specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the French verb *coiffer*, which means *to do (someone's) hair*, the English word *coiffure* generally refers to a hairstyle or previously, a headdress. To be *well-coiffed* is therefore to imply a well-done, well-arranged, stylish hairdo.

Comment: However, modern use is limited and is often restricted to more theatrical or dramatic situations.

Answer (score 2):

Hair is generally implied:

> If for public appearances Zilla was *over-coiffed*, over-painted, and
>   resolutely corseted, for private misery she wore a filthy blue
>   dressing-gown and torn stockings thrust into streaky pink satin mules.
>   [Sinclair Lewis, "Babbitt"]

Or:

> ...only tender-hearted Hecate, *bright-coiffed*, the daughter of
>   Persaeus, heard the girl from her cave... [Homer, "To Demeter"]

Answer (score 2):

The OED says :

> coif :
>
> 1. To provide or cover with a coif; to invest with the sergeant’s coif; to cover as with a coif.
> 2. To dress, arrange, or make up (the hair).

So I would say *well-coiffed* could either mean "wearing a nice hat (or whatever other sort of coif)", or "having the hair nicely done",  according to context.

It seems to me that in the quote from *[Babitt](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1156/1156-h/1156-h.htm)*  given by Gnawme, it could mean either :
in private Zilla "didn't wear a headdress" or "she did not do her hair".

And *Babitt* being set at a time when it was usual for women to wear hats when  dressed up, I am inclined to think the word here means she wore extravagant or excessive hats.

Googling *over-coiffed* I have come upon this sentence "*the over-coiffed and over-fed Puss In Boots*" (referring to the character in the Shrek movies).  Now, knowing the movie, we can easily visualize [Puss In Boots](http://dreamworks.wikia.com/wiki/Puss_in_Boots) and his exuberant hat.

Comment: On the other hand, I have trouble picturing Hecate wearing a bright 'hat' in her cave. :-)

Comment: @Gnawme: so have I, that's why I say it depends on context and to me "well-coiffed" doesn't automatically imply nicely styled hair.

Comment: That's why my answer says 'generally;' and in a modern context, I think that hair is generally implied.